# Stats of Twelfth man if he involved in Caught/Run-outs

Tags: cricket, trivia, statistics

Twelfth man fields when a member of the fielding side is injured. There are so many instances where this Player involve in Caught/Run-outs.

Whether this stats count as his career stat 'or' the Player, for whom he fielded?

(I have this question, since the match will not count for Twelfth man)

Comment: There is a third option of not adding the catch to any player's statistics, just crediting it to "sub". This is what I remember from reading scorecards in the early 1990s in England, and I always thought it was slightly unfair on the substitute fielder not to get his name in the paper.

Answer (score 1):

"Career stats" are not a concept which are rigorously defined by the Laws of the Game, so anything here is going to be based purely on how your chosen stats provider chooses to count things.

That said, we can look at how Cricinfo handles this situation. In the [first Ashes Test of 2005](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/213856.html), James Hildreth caught Ricky Ponting while on as a substitute fielder:

> **27.3** short of a length and outside the off, Ponting cuts but it is uppish and straight to the man at point. James Hildreth, the substitute pouches the simple chance and that's the end of Ponting! **102/3**

It is easy to tell that this is [not recorded on his career statistics](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/analysis.html?search=james+hildreth;submit_analysis.x=0;submit_analysis.y=0) as Hildreth never played a Test Match. While substitutes and 12th men aren't *quite* the same thing, they are very similar once the toss has been made and the teams decided.